# Flex app loading slow without progress bar

Tags: apache-flex, preloading

I have a Flex app., sometimes when you view it, its exactly as expected. Yet sometimes when you view the page it is just blank for like a good minute with no progress bar or any indication to wait. The progress bar is supposed to be automatic in flex. I would like to fix this because I am afraid it is causing us to lose many sales. If it's a Flex bug and there isn't a fix, is there someway I can position the Flex app over some text that says like "Loading.. Please wait" and then when the app loads it covers it? I need to give the user some sort if indication to wait, 60 seconds is way too long with no indication that something is loading.

UPDATE:
Apparently its not loading at all for some users, until the refresh the page.

Comment: How is your web server setup? This doesn't sound like a Flex issue to me.

Comment: I believe its a LAMP setup, we are hosting through a rackspace affiliate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what this is, in IE, the flex app will not appear until you mouse over it. a fix is to set focus to it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setFlexFocus()
{
document.getElementById('EverlonBuilder').focus();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="setFlexFocus()">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom preloader then that could be the problem.  Try to switch out the custom one for the default.  Before the preloader displays the loading progress bar the full first frame of the SWF file must be loaded.  So it's possible that your first frame is very large.  If none of that information helps then the best thing to do is to try to create a reproducible test case and [file a bug](http://bugs.adobe.com/flex).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is timing out trying to download a non-existent "crossdomain.xml" file.